# TableSorter Custom Parser

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, tablesorter

I'm trying to sort values like "200.32 M" or "800.80 B"

The current method I'm using is not working out. Anyone familiar with this?

```
ts.addParser({  
    id: 'mktcap', 
    is: function(s) { 
        return false;   
    }, 
    format: function(s) {   
        return s.replace(/M/,s+1000000).replace(/B/,s+1000000000); 
    },   
    type: "numeric"   
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s.replace(/M/,s+1000000)` looks strange.
try this instead for `M` (and same for `B` etc.)

```
var s = "200.32 M";
s = eval(s.replace(/ M/, " * 1000000"));
// s = 200320000

var s = "800.80 B";
s = eval(s.replace(/ B/, " * 1000000000"));
// s = 800800000000
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure `s.replace(/M/,s+1000000)` won't do what you expect.  Best case scenario, you will end up with a string like "200.32 1000200.32".  I would check for the M, strip it off, cast the string to number, and then add/multiply the appropriate value.  Like this...

```
var str = "200.32 M";
var tokenM = " M";
var num;

if(str.indexOf(tokenM) == (str.length - tokenM.length)) { // Ends with " M"?
  str = str.replace(new RegExp(tokenM), "");
  num = parseFloat(str) + 1000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s= "200.32 M" ;

var rx=/((\.\d+)|(\d+(\.\d+)?))\s*([MB])?/;
var P= rx.exec(s), value, x, 
mult={M:1000000,B:1000000000,O:1};

if(P){
    value= P[1];
    x=P[5] || O;
    value*=mult[x];
}
alert(value)
```

/*  returned value: (Number)
200320000
*/